# Output specific value using port manipulation

Tags: arduino-uno, port-mapping

How can I output a specific value on a pin using port manipulation?

Example: I want to use this code but without any arduino functions, just with port manipulation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
analogWrite(11, i); //write the i value to pin 11
}
```

I want to replace the `analogWrite` function with register manipulation. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course, how do you think `analogWrite` does it?

Comment: @NickGammon Alright, I made some quick research and I am back from where I started. I must actually generate a PWM on that PIN and change the duty cycle acordingly ( basically what analogWrite does). Am I right?

Comment: Have you read the ATmega328 datasheet? This is where you have to start. Taking a look at the implementation of `analogWrite()` might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `analogWrite` function is just an interface to setting up the hardware timers to do PWM (pulse-width modulation). I have a [page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) which you may find helpful.

Depending on which pin you want to output the PWM to, the registers will be slightly different. Here is one example from my page:

```
const byte OUTPUT_PIN = 3;  // Timer 2 "B" output: OC2B

const byte n = 224;  // for example, 1.111 kHz

void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (OUTPUT_PIN, OUTPUT);

  TCCR2A = bit (WGM20) | bit (WGM21) | bit (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2A on compare
  TCCR2B = bit (WGM22) | bit (CS22);         // fast PWM, prescaler of 64
  OCR2A =  n;                                // from table  
  OCR2B = ((n + 1) / 2) - 1;                 // 50% duty cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop() { }
```

---

> How can I output a specific value on a pin ?

I should point out that the only values you can output are +5V or 0V. There is no provision for outputting (say) 3.7V. The only way you can sort-of do this is by using PWM and then running the result through an RC filter. There is an example on [my page about op amps](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11395).

An example circuit could be:

[image: Filter circuit]

This uses a resistor and capacitor to filter out the "ripple" in the PWM, giving you a reasonably smooth output voltage, proportional to the PWM duty cycle.

For a larger range of output values a rail-to-rail op-amp would be preferable.